# Como converter os caracteres dentro do formulário e imprimo em tela?

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço com que os caracteres de `-` sejam convertidos em `:` número dentro do formulário.

[image: form]

Ao colar um número dentro do formulário, como no exemplo acima; quero que os `-` sejam convertidos em `:`, ficando `00:00:00:00`.

```js
function substituiPonto(){
  valor = document.calcform.visor.value;
  document.getElementById("visor").value = valor.replace("-", ":");
}
function tela(){
  window.alert(valor);
}
```

```html
<form name="calcform" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="visor" id="visor" value="" onKeyPress="substituiPonto()"/>
</form>
```

Por esse código eu só consigo que converta enquanto digito, e não converte quando dou `CTRL+V` dentro do formulário.

Comment: Poderia incluir a propriedade `onfocusout="substituiPonto()"` no seu _input_. No seu _JavaScript_, em vez de usar a função `replace()`, usaria `replaceAll()`. Dessa forma, ao retirar o `focus` do seu input, chamaria a função `substituiPonto()`, e faz um _replace_ em todos os `-` por `:`.

Comment: Poderia me mostrar como ficou o código pra você?

Comment: Coloquei na resposta Lucas, veja se resolve seu problema

Comment: Excelente amigo! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocando o `onfocusout="substituiPonto()`, aproveitando sua função `substituiPonto()`, apenas substituindo `replace()` para `replaceAll()`. Quando colar (`CTRL+V`) o formato `00-00-00` por exemplo, e ao sair do seu `input`, ou seja, no evento `onfocusout`, será chamado `substituiPonto()`, substituindo todo `-` encontrado por `:`. Aí já poderia exibir no formato que você quer, utilizando `:`.

```js
function substituiPonto(){
  valor = document.calcform.visor.value;
  document.getElementById("visor").value = valor.replaceAll("-", ":");
}
function tela(){
  window.alert(valor);
}
```

```html
<form name="calcform" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="visor" id="visor" value="" onKeyPress="substituiPonto()" onfocusout="substituiPonto()"/>
</form>
```